# Append text in front of variable within the same line - bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, append

I have this example.text

```
> cat example.text
10.10.44.11 10.10.44.20 xa1-Y xa2-Y xb1-Y xb2-Y xc1-Y xc2-Y xd1-Y xd2-Y
```

and I have this command:
`srxa_host_list=$(echo example.text | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/-.*//')`

**The Ouput:**

```
echo $srxa_host_list
xa1
```

**What I need**: Append *sr* text before "xa1" without creating a new line of code.

```
echo $srxa_host_list
srxa1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. We can do all this with a single `awk` program.

```
awk -F'[ -]' '{print "sr"$3}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting field separator as space and `-` for all the lines. In main program printing `sr` string followed by 3rd field of current line, as per shown output.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `sub` method of `awk` program try following program.

```
awk '{sub(/-.*/,"");print "sr"$3}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** using `sub` function to substitute from 1st occurrence of `-` till last of the line with NULL then printing str string followed by 3rd field.

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using `sed` with `-E`(enabling ERE) option please try following program.

```
sed -E 's/^[^ ]* +[^ ]* +([^-]*)-.*/sr\1/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** using `sed`'s `-E` option to enable ERE(extended regular expression). Then in main program matching from starting `^[^ ]* +[^ ]* +` followed by a capturing group where matching everything before `-` followed by `-.*` and substituting it with `sr` and 1st capturing group.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ srxa_host_list="sr$(sed 's/[^-]* \([^-]*\).*/\1/' example.text)"
$ echo "$srxa_host_list"
srxa1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the value of the 3rd field keeping the default field separator, you can also split on `-` and append the first part to `sr`

```
awk '{split($3, a, "-");print "sr"a[1]}' example.text
```

Output

```
srxa1
```